# $\zeta(s) = \sum_{n\leq x} n^{-s} - x^{1-s}/(1-s) + ...$ through bounded-order Euler-Maclaurin?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

It is a basic classical result (Titchmarsh Thm 4.11; credited to Hardy-Littlewood) that,
uniformly for $\Re s \geq \sigma_0>0$, $t\leq 6 x$ (say),
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{n^s} - \frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s} + O(x^{-\sigma}).$$

Questions:

(a - main) I know two ways of deriving this result: (i) as in Titchmarsh, by "non-stationary phase" combined with first-order Euler-Maclaurin, (ii) by $k$-order Euler-Maclaurin, $k\gg \log x$ (smoothing optional).

Is there some other way? In particular, can one prove the formula using bounded-order Euler-Maclaurin (in some not completely obvious way; the obvious way leads to a difficulty)?

(b) Is uniformity on all of $\Re s > 0$ not possible?

(c) Is there an explicit constant in the literature (that I can quote; I could derive one myself)?

Comment: Here's the funny thing: my collaborators and I are getting $c=2/3$, for all $0\leq \sigma\leq 1$. How come we cannot find a non-explicit version *with uniformity on $\sigma$* in the literature?